# Company device on home wifi

Tags: wifi

I was surfing some risque sites on my home computer, then I realized that my company's Phone was connected tonthe same wifi.  Can the company phone "see" or record what's being done on another computer?

Comment: Do you work for the NSA TAO or something comparable? Then yes :-) In all other cases, most likely no.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. Long answer: If there's no reason to investigate, you're probably good. They could in theory, but it is highly unlikely. If they have installed monitoring software on the device, even then they will usually not directly see what sites you visit at home. That is only easy and legal on their network. What sites you visit on your private network is your private information. Maybe your history logs can be read out, but if you've used private browsing for this it its not a problem.